# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-feign

I have 2 microservices that are communicating via feign. 
One micro-service is exposing a method that the other is calling.
The method takes a date as an argument.

This is the code of the method :

```
@Override
public String verifyWorkingDaysByAccesstimeAndAttendanceDate(@PathVariable int accessTimeId,
        @PathVariable("attendanceDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date attendanceDate) {

    AccessTime accessTime = accessTimeService.findByIDService(AccessTime.class, accessTimeId);

    String day = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE", Locale.ENGLISH).format(attendanceDate).toUpperCase();
    String status = "NOT_VERIFIED";

    if (workingDayservice.findWorkingDaysByAccesstimeAndDate(accessTime, attendanceDate).toString().contains(day)) {
        status = "VERIFIED";
    }

    return status;

}
```

==> as you can see it is taking date and verifying its existance in the database.

the other microservice is using this feign class in order to call this method:

```
@FeignClient(name = "access-control-micro-services-access-time")
public interface AccessTimeClient {

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v${webService.currentVersion}/workingDay/accessTime/{accessTimeId}/{attendanceDate}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String verifyWorkingDaysByAccesstimeAndAttendanceDate(@PathVariable("accessTimeId") int accessTimeId,
        @PathVariable("attendanceDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) Date attendanceDate);
```

==> the second microservice is calling this method in another class and is giving it a date that it is retreiving from the database (format: 2019-03-29 08:38:08)

My code is launching this exception :

> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2019-03-29 08:38:08.0'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: \"2019-03-29 08:38:08.0\" is malformed at \" 08:38:08.0\""

Comment: `Invalid format: \"2019-03-29 08:38:08.0\" is malformed at \" 08:38:08.0\""` what is confusing you about this very explicit error message?

Comment: Well, the exception says: `Invalid format: "2019-03-29 08:38:08.0" is malformed at " 08:38:08.0"` - that's because `08:38:08.0` doesn't fit the [ISO date time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations). Try `2019-03-29T08:38:08` instead.

Comment: i can't change the format of the date in the database. i don't have that authority. my code should use the existing formats

Comment: Well, you don't have to change the format of the dates in the database. Just read (and if they are strings parse) them and reformat when calling the microservice.

Comment: i eliminated that solution because when i parse the date back to date format (after i change it to string and delete the time that i dont need and posing a problem ) i get this long format conatining the name of the day and bla bla bla ... it just doesnt return my yyyy-mm-dd string as a yyyy-mm-dd date :/ :/

Answer (score 1):

Feign client doesn't support `@DateTimeFormat` annotation as per issue [Feign client doesn't serialize java.time.LocalDate's correctly #104](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/104). The `@DateTimeFormat` annotation is used by Spring MVC, not by Spring Cloud OpenFeign.

There are few ways to fix e.g. [force ISO dates for all Feign calls](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/104#issuecomment-232330995) or [register additional Spring converters](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/issues/104#issuecomment-296995475). It will require custom code that depends on your use-case e.g. you might want to replace old `Date` with `ZonedDateTime`.